# Display SQL Column Name as Row value in SSRS matrix

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have the following table as a result of sql query:

[image]

I would like to display the data at the SQL Server Report as the following :

[image]

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done using a SSRS Matrix. Add a matrix set it to use your dataset, and delete the RowGroups.

Add the `Quarter` and `Months` fields to Column Groups Pane:

[image]

Add two rows for columns `A` and `B`, hardcode their name (A and B in this case) in the first column:

[image]

Add `Fields!A.Value` and `Fields!B.Value` to the respective cell next to `A` and `B`.

[image]

It should produce:

[image]

Let me know if this helps.